# C# Project in Visual Studio 2010 for Windows Phone Notefunction

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, web-services, windows-phone-7

Im trying to get my notefunction to post the current city you are in by using your gps coordinates when saving a note. Right now it's only showing "unknown location". Im kinda lost right now and i have worked so long with this code to try and get it to work so please could anyone tell me what i have done wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Device.Location;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.IO;
using Secret.myTerraService;

namespace Secret
{
public partial class AddNotePage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private IsolatedStorageSettings settings =     IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    private string location = "";

    #region Hämtar din geografiska position

    public AddNotePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher;

        watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default)
                           {
                               MovementThreshold = 20
                           };

        watcher.PositionChanged += this.watcher_PositionChanged;
        watcher.StatusChanged += this.watcher_StatusChanged;
        watcher.Start();

    }
private void watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
{
switch (e.Status)
{
    case GeoPositionStatus.Disabled:
        // location is unsupported on this device
        break;
    case GeoPositionStatus.NoData:
        // data unavailable
        break;
}
}

private void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender,   GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
{
var epl = e.Position.Location;

// Access the position information thusly:
epl.Latitude.ToString("0.000");
epl.Longitude.ToString("0.000");
epl.Altitude.ToString();
epl.HorizontalAccuracy.ToString();
epl.VerticalAccuracy.ToString();
epl.Course.ToString();
epl.Speed.ToString();
e.Position.Timestamp.LocalDateTime.ToString();




}

void client_ConvertLonLatPtToNearestPlaceCompleted(object sender,   myTerraService.ConvertLonLatPtToNearestPlaceCompletedEventArgs e)
{
location = e.Result;

//throw new NotImplementedException();
}


    #endregion

    #region Knappfunktioner

    private void AppBar_Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        navigateBack();
    }

    private void AppBar_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { // spara en ny anteckning
        if (location.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            location = "Okänd Plats";
        }

        // skapa namnet på filen
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(DateTime.Now.Year);
        sb.Append("_");
        sb.Append(String.Format("{0:00}", DateTime.Now.Month));
        sb.Append("_");
        sb.Append(String.Format("{0:00}", DateTime.Now.Day));
        sb.Append("_");
        sb.Append(String.Format("{0:00}", DateTime.Now.Hour));
        sb.Append("_");
        sb.Append(String.Format("{0:00}", DateTime.Now.Minute));
        sb.Append("_");
        sb.Append(String.Format("{0:00}", DateTime.Now.Second));
        sb.Append("_");

        location = location.Replace(" ", "-");
        location = location.Replace(", ", "_");
        sb.Append(location);
        sb.Append(".txt");

        //spara filen i Isolated Storage
        var appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        try
        {
            using (var fileStream = appStorage.OpenFile(sb.ToString(),  System.IO.FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(editTextBox.Text);
                }
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            // åtgärda vid senare tillfälle..
        }



        //Klart Navigera tillbaka till NoteMainPage
        navigateBack();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When testing this, I can see a few points where your code could break. You should debug with breakpoints to actually confirm that your app is getting GPS location data. If not, use the Windows Phone emulator and run a GPS simulation (and then confirm again).

Next, once you know that your GPS data is coming in and formatted correctly for your Terra Web Service, confirm that the data is actually being sent to the Terra Web Service and that data is being returned from the web service call. If your Terra Web Service is returning "Unknown Location" still, try again but this time plot the GPS location near a major city to increase the odds of the web service knowing what city you are close to. If you are still returning "Unknown Location" then you can be fairly certain that the issue resides with the web service provider.

In my experience with the Windows Phone location services (I've only used dev phones with WiFi access (i.e. no sim)), location data sometimes takes a few seconds or minutes to pickup. If you're testing this on a physical dev phone in a basement or an area with limited access for the GPS to find you, odds are the data isn't being generated. Also, because the Windows Phone location data isn't necessarily instant, you can't always call it on the fly and expect it to have location data ready. In my experience I have had the user opt in to location services (per the Windows Phone Marketplace submission requirements) and then have a background agent pull location data while the user is using the app. That way location data is likely to be ready by the time user would need it (like your example when the user saves the note).

Here's a working example I made for you in C# that will work for your Windows Phone app. The sample is a console app for the sake of simplicity and time. If you can't figure it out still, I'll code it up for Windows Phone. With this though you really have everything you need to make it work, just plug in the lat and long variables. [Download Working Source Code](http://www.jeremiahisaacson.com/samples/TerraServiceExample.zip) (Visual Studio 2010)

C# Source code snippet

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using TerraServiceExample.com.msrmaps; // add the service using statement
// http://msrmaps.com/terraservice2.asmx
namespace TerraServiceExample
{
    class Program
    {
        /// <summary> The main entry point for the application. </summary>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Create the GPS point from your location services data
            LonLatPt location = new LonLatPt();

            // Modify Lat and Lon based on your needs
            // This example uses the GPS Coordinates for "Eau Claire, Wisconsin, United States"
            location.Lat = 44.811349;
            location.Lon = -91.498494;

            // Create a new TerraService object
            TerraService ts = new TerraService();

            // Output the nearest location from the TerraService
            Console.WriteLine(ts.ConvertLonLatPtToNearestPlace(location));

            // For console app to stay open/close easily
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close window...");
            Console.ReadKey();

            // Lastly, appreciate the Microsoft folks that made this available for free
            // They are all interesting individuals but you should read about Jim Gray via Wikipedia to
            // understand some history behind this cool web service.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried the code by setting location=epl.ToString(); and  run it on my dev phone and it picks up the coordinates and it changes after i have moved to two different cities. The problem i am having now is to convert these coordinates into a city location by using the location= e.result: method (converts) but its not working i need to convert the coordinates recieved to the  var epl. could you help me by  restructuring my code?

Comment: Thanks, But the problem is i did this before and i couldnt get the correct location anyway it just showed me the location that i had hardcoded which in this case is location.lat = 44.811349 and location.lon = -91.498494 I need the phone to get the postion where you really is and not find the hardcoded location

Comment: Sounds great. I will create a working version of this for Windows Phone for you this evening when I have access to a computer with the Windows Phone SDK. Also, I agree that you would not be using a hard coded location like my example, the takeaway from my example was to use code that was a working Terra Service example and add your location services data variables in place of those hard coded values. Since your location services seem to not be working, I will create a minimal app that will display location data based on the location services data pulled from the Windows Phone background agent.

Comment: Don't worry, I haven't forgot about you. I'm busy with family during this holiday season. I will kick out an example soon.

Comment: Ok Sounds Great!  Im really thankfull for the help you have given me. Its understandable i have been busy myself so take your time it's ok! :)

Comment: I could otherwise send my notepages so you could modify them for me if u would like?

Comment: I didn't realize you were writing me. Stack Overflow wasn't pinging me unfortunately. I will have this finished tonight.